# What is the difference between Feeditem object and object specific feed object?

Tags: chatter, feeditem

Forif I say Task, there will be taskfeed as well as feeditem object having the same entry for one chatter feed for a task. what is the diference between these two?

Answer (score 6):

FeedItem is a generic object represents any feed, whereas something like TaskFeed or CaseFeed only applies to that particular object. The main reason for using an object-specific feed object is that the generic FeedItem needs a [high level](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) of permission to query:

**If you are using API version 23.0 or later and have “View All Data” permission, you can directly query for a FeedItem.**

Most users don't (and shouldn't) have that permission, so if you write some code a user can initiate that references FeedItem, you will get an error if they don't have View All Data. But they can query CaseFeed if they have access to Cases.

Comment: Hi @BritishBoyinDC! Does this also mean the following: all the data we have in UserFeed, CaseFeed, TaskFeed, ... XYZFeed is also found in FeedItem? Is it an exact copy?

Comment: I don't think so - I believe FeedItem is the actual object doing the storing - the object specific feeds are just views on that data I think